# PHP Downloaded file is 0 bytes in firefox puzzle

Tags: php, http, download, header, zip

I've been running this test on my website for days now and it still baffles me.

I have a zip file on my server. Within the zip file is a single text file that contains the phrase "this is a test".

In my file api.php, I have the following code:

```
<?php

$originalFileName = "test.zip";

header("content-encoding: none");
header("Content-Type: application/zip");  
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . "test.zip" . "\"");
header("Content-Length: " . filesize($originalFileName));

readfile($originalFileName);

?>
```

When I visit the api.php file in firefox. It prompts to download "test.zip" with a file size of 128 bytes.

When I click save. It creates the file on my desktop, but the file is 0 bytes in size and is empty.

If I visit the url using the direct IP address i.e. http://192.0.0.1/api.php

It downloads the zip file and contains the text file as its suppose to.

The domain is under cloudflare with the caching disabled and developer mode on so it shouldn't be that different.

I used firefox's dev tools to copy the responses from the domain request and the ip request

Domain request - This makes the 0 byte empty zip file

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sat, 01 Jun 2019 10:15:22 GMT
content-disposition: attachment; filename="test.zip"
Content-Length: 128
Content-Type: application/zip
content-encoding: none
Connection: keep-alive
X-Powered-By: PHP/7.2.16
Vary: User-Agent
Alt-Svc: h2=":443"; ma=60
CF-RAY: 4e006d0d4e615629-ORD
Server: cloudflare

UEsDBBQAAAAAADEcwU7q5x4NDgAAAA4AAAAIAAAAdGVzdC50eHR0aGlzIGlzIGEgdGVzdFBLAQIUABQAAAAAADEcwU7q5x4NDgAAAA4AAAAIAAAAAAAAAAEAIAAAAAAAAAB0ZXN0LnR4dFBLBQYAAAAAAQABADYAAAA0AAAAAAA=
```

Direct IP request - This makes the 128 byte zip file

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sat, 01 Jun 2019 10:15:57 GMT
content-disposition: attachment; filename="test.zip"
content-length: 128
Content-Type: application/zip
content-encoding: none
Connection: Upgrade, Keep-Alive
X-Powered-By: PHP/7.2.16
Upgrade: h2,h2c
Vary: User-Agent
Keep-Alive: timeout=5
Server: Apache

UEsDBBQAAAAAADEcwU7q5x4NDgAAAA4AAAAIAAAAdGVzdC50eHR0aGlzIGlzIGEgdGVzdFBLAQIUABQAAAAAADEcwU7q5x4NDgAAAA4AAAAIAAAAAAAAAAEAIAAAAAAAAAB0ZXN0LnR4dFBLBQYAAAAAAQABADYAAAA0AAAAAAA=
```

Both the response payloads are identical and besides a few tiny changes in the response headers.

Such as the letter casing and the cloudflare headers.

I don't see any reason why the zip file should be 0 bytes when trying to save the download prompt through the domain.

When I press ctrl+j to view the download history.
It looks fine for the direct ip download on the bottom and a weird message for the top domain one.

[image]

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to solve this?

Comment: Read my updated answer! I discovered the guilty...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested your issue, maybe changing some `headers` this may solve the question, with my `headers` I can see the zip file downloaded and opening it's fine... let's me know if with my code your question is solved...

```
<?php
  $file = basename("test.zip");
  $downloads_folder = "./";
  header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
  header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
  header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $file . '"');
  header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
  header('Connection: Keep-Alive');
  header('Expires: 0');
  header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
  header('Pragma: public');
  header('Content-Length: ' . sprintf("%u", filesize($downloads_folder . $file)));
  // Open and output file contents
  set_time_limit(0);
  $fh = fopen($downloads_folder . $file, "rb");
  while (!feof($fh)) {
    echo fgets($fh);
    ob_flush();
    flush();
  }
  fclose($fh);
  exit;
?>
```

EDIT: I discovered that the fault is due to `HTTP/2`, if you have a paid account you can disable it ([source](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/214534308-Can-I-disable-HTTP-2-for-my-website-)). Using my code and disabling `HTTP/2` you should solve your issue or you can use `SSL` to solve this issue, seems that `HTTP/2` without `SSL` is causing this [issue](https://serverfault.com/a/741201)...

You can read other threads that have the same Topic:

https://community.cloudflare.com/t/files-can-not-be-downloaded/5598

https://community.cloudflare.com/t/downloads-are-failing-timing-out/7588

https://community.cloudflare.com/t/file-download-from-website-failing/81700

https://community.cloudflare.com/t/unexpected-connection-errors/4366

Finally the assumption of fault:

https://blog.cloudflare.com/the-curious-case-of-slow-downloads/

I hope this helps.

Comment: I set the ssl to flexible and enabled https rewrites on cloudflare, but it made no difference. I did find however, if I rename the output file to test.txt, it downloads fine and if I rename it to test.zip on my desktop, it is a valid zip file.

Comment: Try to disable http/2... if works fine... consider to use http/2 with SSL certificate (https)...

Comment: As you mentioned, you can't disable http/2 unless you're a paid account.

I'm just going to host the download on my second website and have this website redirect to it.

Cloudflare has been very disappointing with this issue.